# having trouble adding three more cube

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

I'm attempting to make a cube, but I can only manage two. As you can see, the third cube is broken. I am having trouble making three more cubes because I am having a hard time understanding vertices and edges.

I tried adding and removing numbers from vertices, and while the faces are sometimes correct and the edges are broken.

Can somebody help me?

Here's the code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

verticies0 = (
    (0, 0.5, -0.5),
    (0.5, 0.5, -0.5),
    (0.5, 0, -0.5),
    (0, 0, -0.5),
    
    (0, 0.5, 0),
    (0.5, 0.5, 0),
    (0.5, 0, 0),
    (0, 0, 0)
    )

edges0 = (
    (0,1),
    (0,3),
    (0,4),
    (2,1),
    (2,3),
    (2,7),
    (6,3),
    (6,4),
    (6,7),
    (5,1),
    (5,4),
    (5,7)
    )

verticies1 = (
    (0.5, 0.5, -0.5),
    (1, 0.5, -0.5),
    (1, 0, -0.5),
    (0.5, 0, -0.5),
    
    (0.5, 0.5, 0),
    (1, 0.5, 0),
    (1, 0, 0),
    (0.5, 0, 0)
    )

edges1 = (
    (0,1),
    (0,3),
    (0,4),
    (2,1),
    (2,3),
    (2,7),
    (6,3),
    (6,4),
    (6,7),
    (5,1),
    (5,4),
    (5,7)
    )

verticies2 = (
    (-0.5, 0.5, 0),
    (0, 0.5, 0),
    (-0.5, 0, 0.5),
    (-0.5, 0, 0),
    
    (0, 0.5, 0),
    (0, 0, 0),
    (0, 0, 0),
    (0, 0, 0)
    )

edges2 = (
    (0,1),
    (0,3),
    (0,4),
    (2,1),
    (2,3),
    (2,7),
    (6,3),
    (6,4),
    (6,7),
    (5,1),
    (5,4),
    (5,7)
    )

def Cube():

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges0:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(verticies0[vertex])
    glEnd()

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges1:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(verticies1[vertex])
    glEnd()

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges2:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(verticies2[vertex])
    glEnd()
    
def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (1200,800)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    gluPerspective(45, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 500)
    button_down = False

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)  
    modelMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
    
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0, -5)

    while True:
        glPushMatrix()
        glLoadIdentity()
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    glTranslatef(-1, 0, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    glTranslatef(1, 0, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    glTranslatef(0, 1, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    glTranslatef(0, -1, 0)
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                if button_down == True:
                    glRotatef(event.rel[1], 1, 0, 0)
                    glRotatef(event.rel[0], 0, 1, 0)
                print(event.rel)

        for event in pygame.mouse.get_pressed():
            print(pygame.mouse.get_pressed())
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
                button_down = True
            elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
                button_down = False

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glMultMatrixf(modelMatrix)
        modelMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)

        glLoadIdentity()
        glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)
        glMultMatrixf(modelMatrix)
        
        Cube()
        
        glPopMatrix()        
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)


main()
```

Comment: This seems like more of a geometry or math problem than a programming problem; if you don't know how you'd design this on paper then you can't put it into code until you figure out the design. But the design requires math/geometry, not programming, to figure out, and this is a site about programming. Maybe another StackExchange site would be more help though.

Comment: @RandomDavis It's more a question of how to set a transformation matrix for each cube than a math question. It is not necessary to define vertices for 5 cubes. 1 cube is enough.

Comment: what is `five-dimensional cube`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cube mesh is completely sufficient. Draw this one cube fife times and use `glTranslate` to move the cubes to different positions in the world. The current transformation matrix can be saved and restored with `glPushMatrix` and  `glPopMatrix`:

```py
for i in range(5):
    glPushMatrix()
    glTranslate(-2+i, 0, 0)
    Cube()
    glPopMatrix()
```

---

[image]

```py
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

verticies = ((0.5, -0.5, -0.5), (0.5, 0.5, -0.5), (-0.5, 0.5, -0.5), (-0.5, -0.5, -0.5),
             (0.5, -0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (-0.5, -0.5, 0.5), (-0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
edges = ((0,1), (0,3), (0,4), (2,1),(2,3), (2,7), (6,3), (6,4),(6,7), (5,1), (5,4), (5,7))

def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])
    glEnd()
    
def main():
    pygame.init()
    display = (800, 600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF|OPENGL)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    gluPerspective(60, (display[0]/display[1]), 0.1, 500)
    button_down = False

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)  
    modelMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)
    
    glTranslatef(0.0,0.0, -5)

    while True:
        glPushMatrix()
        glLoadIdentity()
        
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    glTranslatef(-1, 0, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    glTranslatef(1, 0, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    glTranslatef(0, 1, 0)
                if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    glTranslatef(0, -1, 0)
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
                if button_down == True:
                    glRotatef(event.rel[1], 1, 0, 0)
                    glRotatef(event.rel[0], 0, 1, 0)

        for event in pygame.mouse.get_pressed():
            if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 1:
                button_down = True
            elif pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] == 0:
                button_down = False

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

        glMultMatrixf(modelMatrix)
        modelMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)

        glLoadIdentity()
        glTranslatef(0, 0, -5)
        glMultMatrixf(modelMatrix)
        
        for i in range(5):
            glPushMatrix()
            glTranslate(-2+i, 0, 0)
            Cube()
            glPopMatrix()
        
        glPopMatrix()        
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)

main()
```